# How to call js functions defined in script tag of the erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a layout for PDF (`views/layouts/pdf.html.erb`):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <script>
      function sayHello() {
        return "HAAHAHAhAHAAH"
      }
    </script>
    <style>
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to use that `sayHello()` function inside a p tag in `app/views/invoices/pdf.html.erb`, which gets embedded in `yield` of `layouts/pdf.html.erb`

I tried calling `sayHello()` in different ways like using `<%= javascript: sayHello()%>` etc.. but nothing works.

I also tried keeping `sayHello()` in a separate file and then referencing it in `javascript_pack_tag` in `layouts/pdf.html.erb` which leads to a different error.

Is there any way that I can access that function in html.erb?

Comment: The answer is you don't. Inline script tags are evaluated as the page is being rendered and are generally best avoided. While you can define globals from a script tag `window.sayHello = function(){}` you're really just asking for trouble as it will lead to timing issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your paragraph a class like so:

```
<p class="p_class"></p>
```

then put this

```
<script>
  document.getElementsByClassName('p_class')[0].textContent = sayHello();
</script>
```

at the bottom of your `app/views/invoices/pdf.html.erb` partial.

Comment: I want to call inside a <p> tag in erb file. Calling ‘sayHello()’  at the bottom will not show value inside p tag

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does this work now?